# Php subtract two dates with different dates returns wrong result

Tags: php, strtotime

I am trying to subtract two dates using php.
Dateone is stored in the database while datetwo is the current date.
Now, i have this strange scenario:
Dateone is 23-03-13
Date two is 02-04-13

Using different subtraction methods, give different results.

**Method One - Returns -21**

```
$sqldate ="SELECT exam_date FROM exam_table";
$fetchdate = mysql_query($sqldate);
$rowdate = mysql_fetch_array($fetchdate);
//Fetch the date stored in the database
$dateone = $rowdate['exam_date'];
//Calculate the current date today
$datetwo =date('d-m-y');
//Calculate the diff between the two dates
$datediff = $datetwo-$dateone;
```

In this case, $datediff returns -21

**Method Two - Returns -7639**

```
$sqldate ="SELECT exam_date FROM exam_table";
$fetchdate = mysql_query($sqldate);
$rowdate = mysql_fetch_array($fetchdate);
//Fetch the date stored in the database
$dateone = $rowdate['exam_date'];
//Calculate the current date
$datetwo =date('d-m-y');
//Calculate the diff between the two dates
$datetime1 = strtotime("$dateone");
$datetime2 = strtotime("$datetwo");
//seconds between the two times
$secs = $datetime2 - $datetime1;
$days = $secs / 86400;
```

In this scenario, $days returns -7639

Comment: I assume one of the dates is bigger than the other. Print them at runtime and see.

Comment: In the second one you are using $datetoday but converting to time using $datetwo. Please also write out the result of $dateone, then of $datetwo at run time so that we can actually see the result.

Comment: where is `$datetwo` in **method two** ??

Comment: Yes i have printed them at run time and they display as 23-03-13 and 02-04-13.
Charlie and @karmafunk $datetwo is supposed to be $datetoday. I have edited it to reflect that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yeah issue is because your date format is not standard to get difference. You need to inform your current format to date & convert it to standard one to get correct difference.

```
$datetime1 = DateTime::createFromFormat('d-m-Y', '23-03-13'); #In you case it is considering 13-03-2023
$datetime1->format('d-m-YY');
$datetime2 = DateTime::createFromFormat('d-m-Y', '02-04-13'); #In you case it is considering 13-04-2002
$datetime2->format('d-m-YY');
$interval = $datetime1->diff($datetime2);
echo $interval->format('%R%a days'); #output +10 days
```

[CodeViper Demo.](http://codepad.viper-7.com/ckWUxa)

**Note:** PHP version should be >= 5.3.0.

Comment: This works well, what if i want to store the difference in a variable?

Comment: @Joseph - Instead echo assign to a variable.

Answer (score 0):

Why not make it all in the SQL?

```
"SELECT time_to_sec(datediff(`exam_date`, curdate())) as datedifference FROM exam_table";
```

and only this in PHP:

```
fetch_assoc { $datediff = $row['datedifference'];
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
echo $dateone = '02-04-13';
echo $datetwo = '06-04-13';
echo $datediff = $datetwo-$dateone;
```

Comment: This works very fine, but the problem is when the month varies. In your scenario, if dateone is 02-04-13 and datetwo is 06-05-13, the result will be very different.

Answer (score 0):

**SQL Query will be ideal for this**

```
SELECT DATEDIFF(exam_date,CURDATE()) AS DiffDate FROM exam_table
```

**PHP**

```
$dateone = $rowdate['DiffDate'];
```

Comment: This works, but it gives the result as 3632. What is the problem?

Comment: How do you want the difference to be ? in hours or seconds ? So i could adjust the code.

Comment: The above code should return the difference in days... i assume that there is some problem with the value in the db. Check this link joseph. http://www.w3resource.com/mysql/date-and-time-functions/mysql-datediff-function.php

Answer (score 0):

Why not use `DateTime::diff`? Source : http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.diff.php

```
$datediff = $datetwo->diff($dateone);
echo $datediff;
```

This difference will be in epoch. You would need to convert it to your desired format.